# How to reset limited access over the SharePoint library in online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

I have a SharePoint library in client SP Online portal . The library has unique permission to 5 different SP groups. I can see the permission levels are showing against the groups over library as "Limited Access,Read", "Limited Access, Contribute" etc.

One of the 5 different group contains "Everyone Except External".Although, Although some of the users are unable to view the library.

Please help on this to reset the limited permission issue here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you check those users' permissions? Please make sure thoes users have the right permission to view this library.

Limited access permission level is automatically assigned by SharePoint when you provide access to one specific item. You cannot assign Limited Access permissions directly to a user or group yourself.

For Reference: [Permission levels in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252funderstanding-permission-levels-in-sharepoint-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848)

Comment: Is there any progress on this issue? Comment here if you still need any help.